# Combine reduce and filter Swift

Tags: swift

I have 2 code snippets:

```
let names = ["Scarlet", "Stan", "Mike", "Walter", "Jessie"]

let reduceStr = names.reduce("", { x, y in

    x + y
})

print(reduceStr)


let reduceStrWithFilter = names.filter { (x) -> Bool in

    return x.characters.count > 5
}
```

Im kind of struggle with swift syntax, i want to combine those 2 functions to make filter first, then apply reduce to filtered array.

Comment: It's unclear what are you trying to achieve here, what's the purpose of using reduce?

Comment: @AhmadF just combine all strings in one

Comment: Use `joined()` to combine an array of strings, that is simpler and more effective than `reduce`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier than you might think:

```
let names = ["Scarlet", "Stan", "Mike", "Walter", "Jessie"]

var bothReducedAndFiltered = names.filter { $0.characters.count > 5 }.reduce("", +)
print(bothReducedAndFiltered)
```

Or if you really want to split the 2:

```
var filtered =  names.filter { $0.characters.count > 5 }
var reducedAfterFilter = filtered.reduce("", +)
print(reducedAfterFilter)
```

Or a shorter solution:

```
var bothReducedAndFiltered = names.filter { $0.characters.count > 5 }.joined()
```

**This prints:** `ScarletWalterJessie`

**Explanation:**
In both `filter` and `reduce` methods, `$0` means the current element from the iteration.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Glad I could help!